# Can you use process builder to launch an input form?

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I'm trying to find a way to create an popup form when a record created for only for a certain user. Any idea how i would accomplish this?

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think there is a way to do this by process builder. Honestly it smells a little funny. This sounds like you might be trying to make the problem to fit a certain solution AKA an X-Y Problem [https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378]

Comment: Did you check it?  [https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_action_flow.htm&type=5]

Answer (score 2):

Process Builder does not have an inherent user-interface context - it may be fired from a trigger! So no, you can't initiate user interaction from Process Builder.

There are ways to do this but they all start in the UI layer. In Classic, you can override the record page with Visualforce, or embed a small Visualforce page in the standard layout - either can use conditional rendering to present a message based on the current user, or embed a Flow.

In Lightning Experience, you can use similar tools with a Lightning component that you add to your record page.

In either experience, you can select a different page layout or Lightning Record Page based on the user's profile.

If you're using Lightning, there's a neat technique described by [Andrew Fawcett](https://andyinthecloud.com/2017/12/10/introducing-the-dynamic-flow-component/) based on embedding Flow components in the utility bar, which can do a lot of cool contextual interactions.

Comment: Sorry i meant that i was trying to use process builder to launch a flow, but you can't launch a flow with a screen from process builder

Comment: That's correct. You can use any of the other options above for launching UI interaction, including screen-based flows.

Answer (score 0):

No Process Builder has nothing to do with direct user interactions. It's an automation tool which start a process when a certain event occurs (record created/updated, or invoked by another process). After that the process runs in background and doesn't need user interaction/input.

The tool that you certainly need to look at is [Cloud Flow Designer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_admin_flow_overview.htm&type=5). With it you can build an input form that pops up when a record created for a certain user.

Comment: Sorry i meant that i was trying to use process builder to launch a flow, but you can't launch a flow with a screen from process builder